# I can't upload all my firebase data from all folders in recyclerview, firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have some problems reading data from my firebase using Android Studio.

Firebase:

```html
{
  "Advertisements": {
    "Fg65Rt43Fhjn5js6hGJ": [
      {
        "advertisement_price": "50e",
        "description": "propale skije",
        "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skisell-c295d.appspot.com/o/PostImages%2FZxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1%2F0%2Fthumbnail?alt=media&token=19f41472-cb3e-49fb-8100",
        "title": "cao"
      },
      {
        "advertisement_price": "40e",
        "description": "nesto",
        "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skisell-c295d.appspot.com/o/PostImages%2FZxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1%2F0%2Fthumbnail?alt=media&token=19f41472-cb3e-49fb-8100",
        "title": "isto nesto"
      }
    ],
    "Xd45GhtR569Ds12Xdfiu6": [
      {
        "advertisement_price": "150e",
        "description": "blah",
        "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skisell-c295d.appspot.com/o/PostImages%2FZxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1%2F0%2Fthumbnail?alt=media&token=19f41472-cb3e-49fb-8100",
        "title": "nesto"
      }
    ],
    "Zxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1": [
      {
        "advertisement_price": "100e",
        "description": "elan",
        "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skisell-c295d.appspot.com/o/PostImages%2FZxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1%2F0%2Fthumbnail?alt=media&token=19f41472-cb3e-49fb-8100",
        "title": "skije"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Users": {
    "Zxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1": {
      "city": "Kraljevo",
      "name": "Milutin",
      "profileImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skisell-c295d.appspot.com/o/ProfileImages%2FZxw5nuwqXRfWJmlN93i9xBVq2ml1?alt=media&token=761b55d9-1470",
      "status": "offline",
      "surname": "Nedeljkovic",
      "username": "micocomi"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to upload ALL DATA from firebase to recycler view, but it works only for the first folder with user ID.

here is my function for uploading to recycler view:

The `advertisementRef` are declared in `OnCreate` function, but it is too long so I won't upload the whole method here to avoid mess.

```
//this is the declaration in the OnCreate method
//DatabaseReference AdvertisementsRef;
//AdvertisementsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Advertisements");

private void LoadAdvertisements() {
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Advertisements>().setQuery(AdvertisementsRef.child("Fg65Rt43Fhjn5js6hGJ"), Advertisements.class).build();
                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Advertisements, MyViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Advertisements model) {
                        holder.AdTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
                        holder.AdPrice.setText(model.getAdvertisement_price());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getThumbnailURL()).into(holder.thumbnail1);
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_design, parent, false);
                        return new MyViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };
                adapter.startListening();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oops, something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    AdvertisementsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

I expected that this code will return me just a content of the first folder, but i don't have different solution.

The recycler view is good so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't have any errors, but I expected my code to return data from all folders from database into recycler view but it returns just content form the first folder. I know I added the specific child name into the query but I don't know how to do it other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "return data from all folders"? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the JSON file. The problem is that I want to upload every advertisement from firebase, but user can have more than one advertisement, and they are stored in folders with names like: 0, 1, 2... When I try to make a query to upload content into android studio recycler view, the query uploads just content of the the first user, and I need the content from other user ID's too. I just want to display advertisements from all users that are using app. For example, when I run the program the only data that I get from database is the content of "Fg65Rt43Fhjn5js6hGJ" user.